# How to run migrations on a remote/cloud managed DB? (through CI/CD)

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, migration, continuous-deployment, prisma

**TL;DR**
What is the optimal flow / best practice to run migrations in a CI/CD pipeline against a database without public endpoint?
`GH actions -> connect to remote db (somehow) -> run migration on said db` and how to rollback when deployment failed.

**Problem**
I need to setup a flow to deploy an application and it's database migrations accordingly.
The main issue I come across is that it's best practice to set the database to run **without** having a public endpoint, in a private VPC that matches the application service.
But how does one run migrations from a CI/CD pipeline in this case?

**Current scenario**
The stack here is `nodejs`, `typeorm`, Elastic Beanstalk (EBS) & AWS.

1. Build docker image application code & push to private ECR (`app/dev-api:latest`)
2. Build separate docker that packages the migrations and push it to a separate private ECR. `dbmigrations/dev:latest`
3. As soon as the migrations image is pushed to `dbmigrations/dev:latest`, a `fargate` service boots up that sits in the same VPC as the RDS and runs the migrations.
4. If that `fargate` task runned succesfully, deploy applicationcode to Elastic Beanstalk

   - a) If something goes wrong during deploy to EBS

     - build new docker image
     - push to another ECR that contains "rollback" migration
     - boot up another fargate service
   - b) Exit if all tasks ran succesfully -> Deploy Succesful.

**Next scenario**
Now I'm using following stack: `nodejs`, `prisma` and "App Runner", "RDS" on AWS.

I would like to run the database in a private VPC still, but I'm not sure how I would run `prisma` migrations against a private database.
Also I would think there is a simpler solution than to run separate docker containers to run your database migrations, as this can cause a miss-sync between the deployed application and the database.

I know there are tools like `liquibase` & `flyway` but both are paid (I think), and since `prisma` comes with a migration flow itself, I don't see why I would need *yet another* migration tool to do such task.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm using Github Actions, but I'm more looking to a general flow. I'm not looking for a code example (as I'm sure this will apply to other pipeline services as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that you shouldn't expose public IP's on databases or instances that do not require to be accessible from the internet. But such servers should still be accessible by developers for maintenance/debugging etc.

Here comes a Bastion host, which is a central secure proxy that allows you to connect to private servers. You could open a tunnel through Bastion to RDS and run migration.

On AWS there is also newer safer solution (you still need bastion though), called Session Manager that allows you to connect to servers more securely https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html

Comment: Session Manager looks very promising. Although, I'm currently stuck here, and none of the solutions seem to be fixing the issue. Any experience with it yourself? 
I followed this guide front to back and back to front:https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/securely-connect-to-an-amazon-rds-or-amazon-ec2-database-instance-remotely-with-your-preferred-gui/

same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64001338/aws-system-manager-start-session-an-error-occurred-targetnotconnected-when-ca

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. You can't connect to RDS with session manager without bastion. That would be against networking good practices. Session manager just provides better solution over standard ssh connection to bastion.

Comment: I got that :) I setup a bastion with the guide (first link). However the connection still isn't working as the guide shows. Everything I tried, I get "targetnotconnected"

Comment: Some part of networking is probably still blocking. Try to connect just to bastion, than from bastion to rds. You can get more info from CloudTrail